# Why block signals then unblock them?

Tags: c, linux, signals, semaphore

When reading certain source code that involves v4l2 APIs, I stumbled upon these segments:

First:

```
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);
sigaddset(&set, SIGALRM);
sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&set, SIGTERM);
sigaddset(&set, SIGHUP);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &old);
```

Then:

```
pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &old, NULL);
```

In between:

```
if (s->pframe >= 0) {
    if (xioctl(s->fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &s->buf) == -1) {
        motion_log(LOG_ERR, 1, "%s: VIDIOC_QBUF", __FUNCTION__);
        return -1;
    }
}

memset(&s->buf, 0, sizeof(struct v4l2_buffer));

s->buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
s->buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

if (xioctl(s->fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &s->buf) == -1) {

    /* some drivers return EIO when there is no signal, 
       driver might dequeue an (empty) buffer despite
       returning an error, or even stop capturing.
    */
    if (errno == EIO) {
        s->pframe++; 
        if ((u32)s->pframe >= s->req.count) s->pframe = 0;
        s->buf.index = s->pframe;

        motion_log(LOG_ERR, 1, "%s: VIDIOC_DQBUF: EIO (s->pframe %d)", __FUNCTION__, s->pframe);

        return 1;
    }

    motion_log(LOG_ERR, 1, "%s: VIDIOC_DQBUF", __FUNCTION__);

    return -1;
}

s->pframe = s->buf.index;
s->buffers[s->buf.index].used = s->buf.bytesused;
s->buffers[s->buf.index].content_length = s->buf.bytesused;
```

My honest guess is that blocking signal prevents, in this particular case, the setup process being interrupted. But I'm completely unsure. Please help?

Comment: Could you show the code in the actual order? Putting the in-between code after the other code is confusing.

Comment: Your guess looks correct to me. It's blocking those signals, doing the setup, then restoring the signal mask to what it was before.

Comment: I guess you don't want to allow the video buffer to be in an intermediate state, partially initialized.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr1/zlocking.htm

your guess is correct, it is supposed to prevent thread interruptions.
the link above isnt specific to pthreads but the concept is the same and is explained well i think

edit:
pthreads explanation on blocking signals 
http://maxim.int.ru/bookshelf/PthreadsProgram/htm/r_40.html